# Debugging invalid syntax error in ArcPy script with cursor and where clause?

Tags: arcpy, sql, cursor

I've been trying to write a stand alone script to run any query from python, but I've run into a few problems. At first I tried this:

```
fc = "U:\RealGDB.gdb\acutalLayerName" 
Where = """"TOTAL NUMB FLOORS" = 2""" #TOTAL NUMB FLOORS is the actual field name.
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ("'TOTAL NUMB FLOORS'"), Where)

for row in cursor: #python crashes here
    print (row[0])
```

This crashes python. I've spent about a week trying to fix this and I can safely say that I'm completely lost. Every time I change the sql format to something else - when I add some quotes or brackets - I get an invalid syntax error. What's wrong with my sql; why does it cause python to crash at my for loop?

I imported arcpy and os. The table has about 84.4 records.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Defining fields in tables](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/design-defining-fields-in-tables.htm) page in the Online Help (with my bolding) says:

> Field names must also start with a letter and **not contain spaces**
>   or reserved words.

There may be other issues too so try using a field which does not have spaces (like FLOORS) in its name and run this as a test:

```
fc = r"U:\RealGDB.gdb\acutalLayerName" 
where_clause = "FLOORS = 2"
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["FLOORS"], where_clause) as cursor:
    for row in cursor: 
        print row[0]
```

Some other things I did were:

- renamed the variable from `Where` to `where_clause` - sometimes using a keyword (which `Where` may or may not be) can cause errors so I try to avoid them
- used `with` syntax as illustrated in the arcpy.da cursor documentation.  The advantages of this are I think documented there and in other Q&As here.
- the structure of the `where_clause` is the simplest one that I know would do what you appeared to be trying to - they can get much more complex as illustrated in MANY Q&As here

Comment: Isn't that code the same thing as my code without spaces in the field name? Why did you choose to use a with clause?

Comment: how did you know to use only one set of quotation marks in where_clause? Would you use more if this were a more complicated query?

Comment: @Steve There are many correct and many incorrect ways to form where_clauses for use with ArcPy.  In this case, which used a number/integer there is no need to surround the value with quotes like you would need to for a string, and there is no need to surround the field names with quotes, and so only one set of outer quotes is needed.